# Finding the length from a point to a center of the circle.

Tags: geometry, circles

In the diagram, $AB = 2$ and $BP = 6.$ If the radius of the circle is 11, find the distance from $P$ to the center of the circle.

[image]

How can I use power of a point here to find the length of P to the center of the circle? What is the relation of the given values with the length that needs to be found?

Comment: Let $CD$ be such diameter that continuation of $CD$ meets $P$. Then $PA\cdot BP=PC\cdot PD$ hence we find $PC$ and $PD$ given their difference is $CD=22$ and hence we find $\frac{PC+PD}{2}=$ the desired length.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the Pythagorean theorem.  If $O$ is the center of the circle, draw the perpendicular to $AB$ from $O$ and let the foot of the perpendicular be point $M$.  Then because $AO = BO = 11$, $\triangle AOB$ is isosceles and altitude $OM$ bisects $AB$.  So $AM = BM = 1$.  Now draw $OP$ to make $\triangle PMO$, which has a right angle at $M$.  Then two applications of the Pythagorean theorem solve for $OP$:  $$BO^2 = OM^2 + BM^2, \\ OP^2 = PM^2 + BM^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

By using the power of a point formula, we can write

$$PA.PB = OP^2-R^2= \; power \; of \; P$$

thus

$$OP^2=8.6+11^2=169$$

and
$$OP=13$$